# java hashtag counter csv file

Tags: java, csv, hashtag

I am trying to count the amount of times a hashtag appears in a CSV file. The problem is, I'm skipping the last line of every column and instead of counting 75 things, it only counts 70. Here is the code, sorry I'm new at Java and it's probably something simple but I can't figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class HashtagCounter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;

    File file = new File("hashtags.csv");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

    System.out.println("Please enter a hashtag");
    String keyboard = input.nextLine();



    while(scan.hasNext()){
        //System.out.println(scan.next());
        total = total + 1;

        if(scan.next().equals(keyboard)){
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }


    System.out.println("The hashtag " + keyboard + " appears " + count + " time(s), out of a total of " + total + " entries");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're joining last entry of row with first entry of the next row. It's because of your delimiter `",\\s*"` - it matches commas, but after the last entry in csv there is no comma. Use `"\n|,\\s*"` to match either newline character (`\n`) or comma. Pattern `A|B` matches strings that match either of sub-patterns. It's documented in: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: That returns a value of 0 matches with 571 entries. I'm not sure why but I don't think it makes it optional.

Comment: @MikeAvery, what about `"\n|,\\s*"`?